# how to select a sentence from a text with c++

Tags: c++, file

i have a question, how to separate one file .txt into 3 files based on the keywords using c++. so each keyword has it's own sentence. so each new sub file contains keywords with their respective sentences. i have tried to show it on console, and it works, but i can't separate the text by it's keywords.
so i have a file. every sentence in this file
so I have a file. There are many sentences here. So, every sentence starts with the words error, warning, and information. how to separate each sentence starting with each of these words, and make them 3 separate files
can you help me please?

i've tried this code, and its failed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;
int main(){
  ifstream myFile;
  string data,output,buffer, line;
  bool isData = false;

  myFile.open("try.txt");

  while(getline(myFile, buffer)){   

   if (buffer == "Error"){
   getline(myFile,buffer);
   cout<< buffer <<endl;

    } 
    }
  cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `operator==`, use `std::string::find` instead.

Comment: woww it's work, thanks for your information